# .NET Core - why does AsyncLocal<> reference build on Windows, but not Linux (netstandard2.0)

Tags: linux, .net-core, .net-standard

My project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Description>Redacted</Description>
    <VersionPrefix>2.0.0</VersionPrefix>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>Redacted</AssemblyName>
    <PackageId>Redacted</PackageId>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

My code:

```
using System.Threading;
// ...
_context = new AsyncLocal<SomeClass>();
```

Building locally, .NET SDK 2.1.401, Windows 10, from `dotnet build` commandline or VS 2017, no problem.  Couple of warnings about async methods with no awaits (not related).

Building on Travis CI, .NET SDK 2.1.401, Ubuntu Trusty:

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AsyncLocal<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Do you happen to have the build logs from the linux VM?

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of the cause, but the solution in my case was that I was building with `dotnet msbuild /t:Restore;Pack`.

More details on GH: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/9993

I have no idea how I came to use `/t:Restore;Pack` - but apparently, `/t:Restore;anything` is not a good idea.